# NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToTypeMismatchException : Can not return value of type Task`1 for IDisposable.Dispose (expected type Void)

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await, mocking, nsubstitute

I have code that I want to unit test by substituting and return the list of users:

```
var users = await _context.MyCollection.FindAsync(filter).Result.ToListAsync();
```

Here is my unit test using nsubstitute:

```
 // Arrange
 var user = new MyUsers{ Id = "1" };

 var cursorSub = Substitute.For<IAsyncCursor<MyCollection>>();
 cursorSub.MoveNext().Returns(true);
 cursorSub.Current.Returns(MyUsers);

 var filter = Substitute.For<FilterDefinition<MyCollection>>();
 _context.MyCollection.FindAsync(filter).Returns(cursorSub); 
 
 // Act
 await MyMethod.ExecuteAsync(useCaseRequest);
```

When I debug:

> The substitution for _context.MyCollection.FindAsync(filter) actually works because it returns the cursorSub in the example. However, when it get to the part of the code where it gets the result ".Result.ToListAsync();" the lists becomes empty.
> Can you help me substitute my code?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Something that can be compiled and run by anyone.

Comment: What does ToListAsync do under the covers? IAsyncCursor has a MoveAsync method that you are not setting up, could be a starting point. I assume this is MongoDB; for efcore the ToListAsync methods need a provider set up, may be another avenue to look at.